# How can i find all combinations of K elements of a given set of N elemets without a recursion?

Tags: c

I tried to program something in C but it goes too deep for me…

I have studied a relevant paper "*A CONTROL STRUCTURE FOR A VARIABLE NUMBER OF NESTED LOOPS, Skordalakis, Papakonstantinou*", I have tried to transfer the flow chart proposed in C, but it is not possible with structured programming. The idea should be something like:

```
b1 = 1; 
    
for (m = 1 ; m <= K ; m++) {
   for (i[m] = b[m] ; i[m] <= n; i[m]++) {
        if ( m < K ) {
            a[m] = i[m];
            b[m+1] = i[m] + 1;
            break;
        }
        a[m] = i[m];
        if ( i[m] < n ){
            i[m] = i[m] + 1;
            m = m - 1;
            continue;
        }
    }
}
```

`i` is the control variable for every loop (an array), `b` is the starting parameter for every loop (an array again) and the a array holds every combination.
I have seen some solutions to similar problems that they use a boolean flow control variable (also proposed in the paper).

Can somebody advise?

Comment: So this is all 1-based and has single-letter variable names?  Original in FORTRAN?  Also, this may go through the combinations, but it doesn't do anything when it finds one, so what's the point?

Comment: I _think_ you want to increment over a vector of `N` elements, where each element can have a max value of `M` and generate all possible combinations? That would require [ordinarily] require _nested_ `for` loops with a nesting depth of `N`. You want to do this without having do hand code these nested loops [because `N` could be variable and arbitrarily large]. If so, see my answer: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/238731/compute-the-value-of-a-hand-at-contract-bridge-for-every-possible-hand/238957#238957 Look at `handinc` and `dotest`

Comment: Is the reason to avoid recursion performance? Or assignment requirements?

Comment: @stark: Original was in fortran, yes. As soon as the a array consumes a solution, it can be printed or stored and go for the next one. at tucket: it is assignment requirement, and a tribute to computer science :), at Craig Estey thanks, i hope i will find time to check. The idea is what you mention: to find all vectors a = (a1,a2,...,ak) of size K from a direct product space X1xX2x...xXK where a[j-1]<a[j], j=2,3,...,K and 1<=a[j]<=N.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one possible solution that just occured to me.

Given a set of n elements, we can represent a choice of k elements as a binary number.

For example, with n=6 and k=2, we could choose the second and last elements:

```
010001
```

We could just enumerate the binary numbers of n digits, and discard the ones that don't have exactly k ones.

For example, with n=4 and k=2.

```
0000
0001
0010
0011 ✓
0100
0101 ✓
0110 ✓
0111
1000
1001 ✓
1010 ✓
1011
1100 ✓
1101
1111
```

But that's too many wasted iterations.

So I thought about making a sequence that generates only the numbers with exacly k ones.
For Example, with n=6 and k=3, I would enumaterate as follows:

```
1 1 1 0 0 0 
1 1 0 1 0 0 
1 0 1 1 0 0 
0 1 1 1 0 0 
1 1 0 0 1 0 
1 0 1 0 1 0 
0 1 1 0 1 0 
1 0 0 1 1 0 
0 1 0 1 1 0 
0 0 1 1 1 0 
1 1 0 0 0 1 
1 0 1 0 0 1 
0 1 1 0 0 1 
1 0 0 1 0 1 
0 1 0 1 0 1 
0 0 1 1 0 1 
1 0 0 0 1 1 
0 1 0 0 1 1 
0 0 1 0 1 1 
0 0 0 1 1 1
```

If you take some time to think about it, you will start to understand how the algorithm would work.

We initialize the array with all the(k) ones at the beginning. We are shifting them to the end in some way, and we keep going until all the ones are at the end.

Try to implement that yourself without looking at the solution: https://ideone.com/aY9YBl

Comment: I think this is a very smart alternative. It seems that bitwise operations have an answer for almost all problems :). I will start working on that, thank you.

Comment: Here is a description of the idea: Starting with all 1's on the left, from left to right find the first sequence of  consecutive 1's. Move the rightmost 1 a spot to the right, then move the remaining 1's of the sequence to the left as much as possible. Keep repeating the process until all 1's are to the right.